# sql list number of people born every year

Tags: sql

I have a table with two columns, name and year of birth(from 1960-1980). How can I write a single sql query which lists each year and the number of people born that year? something like:

```
      Year     Number of people born
      1960     5
      1961     3
      1962     4
      ...      ..
      1980     4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select Year, Count(*) as 'Number of people born' From SomeTable
GROUP BY Year
ORDER BY Year ASC
```

Comment: `Select Year, Count(*) as 'Number of people born' From SomeTable GROUP BY Year ORDER BY Year ASC`

Comment: Ok, I guess I can provide the headings :-)

Comment: Thank you, also I have a question - how can I order by the number of people born from highest to lowest?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT YEAROFBIRTH, COUNT(*) FROM YOURTABLE GROUP BY YEAROFBIRTH
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
SELECT MONTH(BIRTHDAY), COUNT(*)
FROM STUDENT
GROUP BY MONTH(BIRTHDAY)
```

Comment: the question is "list for every year" and not for every month.